# ensure the single jobs not executed parallel in spring batch

Tags: java, spring

Recently working on Spring Batch using scheduler, need assistance to ensure that the **single jobs not executed parallel** in spring batch.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the `SyncTaskExecutor`, it will run jobs sequentially